# How to get rid of unnecessary lines with emgu cv

Tags: c#, computer-vision, emgucv

I'm trying to detect contour of an ellipse-like water droplet with Emgu CV. I wrote code for contour detection:

```
    public List<int> GetDiameters()
    {
        string inputFile = @"path.jpg";

        Image<Bgr, byte> imageInput = new Image<Bgr, byte>(inputFile);

        Image<Gray, byte> grayImage = imageInput.Convert<Gray, byte>();

        Image<Gray, byte> bluredImage = grayImage;
        CvInvoke.MedianBlur(grayImage, bluredImage, 9);

        Image<Gray, byte> edgedImage = bluredImage;
        CvInvoke.Canny(bluredImage, edgedImage, 50, 5);

        Image<Gray, byte> closedImage = edgedImage;           
        Mat kernel = CvInvoke.GetStructuringElement(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ElementShape.Ellipse, new System.Drawing.Size { Height = 100, Width = 250}, new System.Drawing.Point(-1, -1)); 
        CvInvoke.MorphologyEx(edgedImage, closedImage, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.MorphOp.Close, kernel, new System.Drawing.Point(-1, -1), 0, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Replicate, new MCvScalar());
       System.Drawing.Point(100, 250), 10000, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar()

        Image<Gray, byte> contoursImage = closedImage;
        Image<Bgr, byte> imageOut = imageInput;
        VectorOfVectorOfPoint rescontours1 = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();
        using (VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint())
        {
            CvInvoke.FindContours(contoursImage, contours, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.List,
                Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.LinkRuns);
            MCvScalar color = new MCvScalar(0, 0, 255);

            int count = contours.Size;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                using (VectorOfPoint contour = contours[i])
                    using (VectorOfPoint approxContour = new VectorOfPoint())
                    {
                        CvInvoke.ApproxPolyDP(contour, approxContour,
                            0.01 * CvInvoke.ArcLength(contour, true), true);

                        var area = CvInvoke.ContourArea(contour);

                    if (area > 0 && approxContour.Size > 10)
                    {
                        rescontours1.Push(approxContour);
                    }

                        CvInvoke.DrawContours(imageOut, rescontours1, -1, color, 2);
                    }                   
            }
        }          
    }
```

result so far:

[image]

I think there is a problem with approximation. How to get rid of internal lines and close external contour?

Comment: Did you try thresholding? Seems relatively easy to detect the droplet outline there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might need some more information to exactly pinpoint your issue, but it might be something to do with your median blur. I would see if you are blurring enough that EmguCV things the blur is enough that you can canny edge detection. Another method that you could use is Dilate. Try Dialating your Canny edge detection and see if you get any better results.

**EDIT**

Here is the code below

```
    public List<int> GetDiameters()
    {
        //List to hold output diameters
        List<int> diametors = new List<int>();

        //File path to where the image is located
        string inputFile = @"C:\Users\jones\Desktop\Image Folder\water.JPG";

        //Read in the image and store it as a mat object
        Mat img = CvInvoke.Imread(inputFile, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ImreadModes.AnyColor);

        //Mat object that will hold the output of the gaussian blur
        Mat gaussianBlur = new Mat();

        //Blur the image
        CvInvoke.GaussianBlur(img, gaussianBlur, new System.Drawing.Size(21, 21), 20, 20, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Default);

        //Mat object that will hold the output of the canny
        Mat canny = new Mat();

        //Canny the image
        CvInvoke.Canny(gaussianBlur, canny, 40, 40);

        //Mat object that will hold the output of the dilate
        Mat dilate = new Mat();

        //Dilate the canny image
        CvInvoke.Dilate(canny, dilate, null, new System.Drawing.Point(-1, -1), 6, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.BorderType.Default, new MCvScalar(0, 0, 0));

        //Vector that will hold all found contours
        VectorOfVectorOfPoint contours = new VectorOfVectorOfPoint();

        //Find the contours and draw them on the image
        CvInvoke.FindContours(dilate, contours, null, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RetrType.External, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.ChainApproxMethod.ChainApproxSimple);
        CvInvoke.DrawContours(img, contours, -1, new MCvScalar(255, 0, 0), 5, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LineType.FourConnected);

        //Variables to hold relevent info on what is the biggest contour
        int biggest = 0;
        int index = 0;

        //Find the biggest contour
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.Size; i++)
        {
            if (contours.Size > biggest)
            {
                biggest = contours.Size;
                index = i;
            }
        }

        //Once all contours have been looped over, add the biggest contour's index to the list
        diametors.Add(index);

        //Return the list
        return diametors;
    }
```

The first thing you do is blur the image.
[image]

Then you canny the image.
[image]

Then you dilate the image, as to make the final output contours more uniform.
[image]

Then you just find contours.
[image]

I know the final contours are a little bigger than the water droplet, but this is the best that I could come up with. You can probably fiddle around with some of the settings and the code above to make the result a little cleaner.

Comment: i will try, i can provide any information that might be helpful

Comment: Could you post a link to the original image?

Comment: I would just fiddle around with some of the code above and see if you can improve my results above. Sorry to leave it kind of open ended, but this is as far as I think I can do it. Personally, I would try to a mess around with the sobol function, and see if you can improve that, which in turn would also improve the dilate and find contours functions. Another way, but the poor mans method, would be to just find how many pixel values the contour is hanging out, and just subtract from the contour's size.

Comment: Also similar to what Cris said above, you could also try thresholding instead of canny to see where that gets you.